# Place Widget in Center of Body: tabBarView()

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to place `stateless` widgets, defined outside the main code section, in the center of the body of a 3 tab tabBar app but cannot make it work. I was able to do it when I had icons in the body but when I put the widgets outside the `AppBar` doesn't display. When I run the below code I get a blank screen (I only included the relevant code):

`main.dart`

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true, colorScheme: lightColorScheme),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true, colorScheme: darkColorScheme),
      home: const Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const int tabsCount = 3;
    return DefaultTabController(
      initialIndex: 1,
      length: tabsCount,
       child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar( // components 
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: <Widget>[ // Tabs components ],  // Widget
         ), // TabBar
       ), //AppBar
        body: TabBarView(children: [
          Center(child: firstWidget()),
          Center(child: secondWidget()),
          Center(child: thirdWidget())
        ]), //tabBarView
      ), // Scaffold
    ); DefaultTabController
  }
}

// first Widget
class firstWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  firstWidgetApp createState() => firstWidgetApp();
}

class firstWidgetApp extends State<firstWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return firstWidget( // DO STUFF );
  }
}

// second Widget
class secondWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  secondWidgetApp createState() => secondWidgetApp();
}

class secondWidgetApp extends State<secondWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return secondWidget( // DO STUFF );
  }
}

// third Widget
class thirdWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  thirdWidgetApp createState() => thirdWidgetApp();
}

class thirdWidgetApp extends State<thirdWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return thirdWidget( // DO STUFF );
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

And how do I get the stateless widgets in the center of the body element of each respective tab?

tried to center as seen in the code...

Comment: tabbarview will take whole screen as dimension. and default will align top-left.
if you want to center, you need to center the children too. not only the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where the problem is in your code, since the part you've provided does not compile. I've adjusted as little as possible in the code to make things work as expected I guess. With the solution below, you have 3 tabs and each one is displaying in the TabBarView centered text, from each of the stateless widgets defined outside of the main widget.

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      home: const Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const int tabsCount = 3;
    return DefaultTabController(
      initialIndex: 1,
      length: tabsCount,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(child: Text("1", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))),
              Tab(child: Text("2", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))),
              Tab(child: Text("3", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))),
            ],
          ),
        ), //AppBar
        body: TabBarView(children: [
          Center(child: firstWidget()),
          Center(child: secondWidget()),
          Center(child: thirdWidget())
        ]), //tabBarView
      ), // Scaffold
    );
  }
}

// first Widget
class firstWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  firstWidgetApp createState() => firstWidgetApp();
}

class firstWidgetApp extends State<firstWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('Text1');
        }
}

// second Widget
class secondWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  secondWidgetApp createState() => secondWidgetApp();
}

class secondWidgetApp extends State<secondWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('Text2');
        }
}

// third Widget
class thirdWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  thirdWidgetApp createState() => thirdWidgetApp();
}

class thirdWidgetApp extends State<thirdWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('Text3');
        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I did the same as your code but you reply first.. your code looks like mine with the same result.. I didn't figure out what chuckd833 error is.

Comment: thanks. I thought I had the correct syntax. I copied and pasted your code and re-added the decorations and it works. Not sure what it was in my code.

Answer (score 0):

As @Karzel mentioned, the following code for class (Home) will do a good job..

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const int tabsCount = 3;
    return DefaultTabController(
      initialIndex: 1,
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('TabBar'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.cloud_outlined),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.beach_access_sharp),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.brightness_5_sharp),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Text("It's cloudy here"),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text("It's rainy here"),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text("It's sunny here"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```